# view the most recently added packages in Arch Linux's official repositories

Tags: arch-linux, package-management, repository

I read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository) that packages in Arch Linux's AUR can be promoted to the official repositories. I also read [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/official_repositories) that packages can be promoted between the *community*, *extra*, & *core* repositories. So is there a way to see the packages which have been most recently added to the official repositories?

*Note*: I know I can view all of the packages in the official repositories [here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/). On that page, there is a way to sort the packages by date updated, but not date added.

Comment: Maybe you need to access ALA since a package doesn't have a property called added-to-repo-date. Also, package name might change, packages might get split or merged, what are you trying to achieve specifically? Please define "adding to repo", if package get split and renamed, are new names count as newly-added?

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything specifically. I just think it would be interesting to browse the newest packages. Regarding the issue of counting or not counting split/merged/renamed packages, it doesn't matter too much to me. If there's a way to do either, I'd be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** I found a way to do this faster natively with `git log`.

---

Clone the Arch repositories you're interested in, eg.:

```
git clone https://git.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git
```

Enter the repository.

```
cd packages
```

Use [git log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25633731/4700618) on every PKGBUILD file from the repositories and let it filter the logs for when it was added to the repositories, then format the respective commit to only show the timestamp and the file name.

```
git --no-pager log --diff-filter=A --name-only --pretty=format:%aD -- **/extra-x86_64/PKGBUILD
```

It sorts reverse chronologically by default. You can limit the time it looks back with the parameter `--since=5months`. Replace `extra-x86_64` with your favourite repository.

Comment: N.B. that cloning the repository uses 453M of space. Also, the `find…` command was very slow for me, reading only 8 packages in 5 minutes. Hence, it would take over 25 hours to update all packages.

Comment: Indeed, the find command took about 16 hours on my laptop. The `git log` command is searching through at most 346486 commits for each of the 2417 files. Here is the result so you don't have to run it: https://pastebin.com/WA32pRNX

Comment: +1 looks like it works in theory. I'm assuming the question is more about wanting to run the command frequently though.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as I think it is most likely the only solution